# How to convert array values into different objects

Tags: javascript

I am having an array values with multiple values< i want that array values to split into different objects

```
let array = [{"condition":"equals","field_name":"name","value":["Company B","Company D"]}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{"condition": "equals",
    "field_name": "name",
    "value": ["Company B"]
},
{
    "condition": "equals",
    "field_name": "name",
    "value": ["Company D"]
}
],
```

Comment: Its better if you show us your efforts as well. Community will help in solving the issues you face while trying yourself., not providing you the working code.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal : you'll see the rat race below this question in less than 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```js
let things = [{"condition":"equals","field_name":"name","value":["Company B", "Company D"]}];

function expand(xs){
 var results = [];
 
 xs.forEach(item => {
   if (item.value && item.value.length > 1){
     results.push(...item.value.map( v => Object.assign({}, item, {value: [v]})))
   }
   else{
     results.push(item)
   }
 })
 
 return results;
}

console.log(expand(things))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArr = array.map(item => item.value.map(val => { return { ...item, value: val} }));
```

This should achieve the desired result of the question if I understood correctly.

Comment: Perhaps provide an explanation to what this does?

Answer (score 0):

I might be over-complicating things, but here is my suggested solution.

You can make use of [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and iterate for each object within the original `array`, followed by iterating within `value`, such that there is one object for each element within the `value` property. This is followed by concatenating them to form the resulting array.

```js
let array = [{"condition":"equals","field_name":"name","value":["Company B","Company D"]}];

const res = [].concat(...array.map(({'condition', 'field_name', 'value'}) =>
  value.map(value => ({'condition', 'field_name', 'value'}))
));

console.log(res);
```